# Cannot Get Object Reference to Deserialize using DataContractSerializer

Tags: c#, datacontractserializer

I'm attempting to use DataContractSerializer to read an xml file and instantiate objects from the xml but unable to get an object reference to deserialize properly. I'm going to be using WCF in the near future, and had read that DataContractSerializer is used within WCF.

I've used XMLSerializer in the past and had no problems.

Below is a simple example which illustrates the problem. The value for Child->Age is coming back as 0 instead of the value in the XML. I've been trying to figure this out for awhile with not much luck.

I originally was getting back the Child object as null but decided to run the code one more time and now the Child is getting instantiated but the Age value is not being set.I'm not sure why - just another thing to confuse me :)

---

### Result

---

- parent

  - Child = instantiated

    - Age = 0 This is the problem. Earlier on, this was null and I'm not sure
                    what changed to cause it be instantiated.
  - FirstName = "Joe"
  - LastName = "Smith"

---

### Classes

---

```
[DataContract(Namespace="")]  
public class Parent  
{  
    [DataMember]  
    public Child Child;  
    [DataMember]  
    public string FirstName;  
    [DataMember]  
    public string LastName;  
}  

[DataContract]  
public class Child  
{  
    [DataMember]  
    public int Age;  
}
```

---

### Code

---

```
XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(System.IO.File.OpenRead("D:/Sandbox/WebApplication1/xml/parent.xml"));  
DataContractSerializer ser = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(Parent));  
Parent parent = (Parent)ser.ReadObject(reader, true);
```

Comment: Can we see the xml file contents?

Comment: I had added the XMl to the post but I guess it got stripped out? Please be patient as I'm new to the StackOverFlow site/interface.  Here is the XML. Hopefully it gets added to the post. <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Parent>
 <Child>
  <Age>15</Age>
 </Child>
    <FirstName>Joe</FirstName>
 <LastName>Smith</LastName>
</Parent>

Comment: I decided to try changing the the order of the xml elements (I did this already multiple times but without success) based on reading numerous posts about deserializing and order. I moved the Child element between the FirstName and LastName elements. I reran my code and the Child object is now null (not instantiated). I then moved the Child back to the way it was earlier (1st in the order of elements). You would think that when re-running the code, the object would be instantiated and the Age value == 0 like it was earlier but the Child is null. I'm not sure what's going on.

Comment: Anyone have any ideas? I've read so many posts and have not found many examples deserializing a class that has a reference to another class. I have learned much about DataContractSerializer but have not gotten this to work :)

I ran some sample code from a Microsoft site which uses an XmlDictionaryReader to loop through the elements and this allows the retrieval of the values in the Child instance. I believe I'm not specifying the correct combination of DataContract/DataMember attributes and values. 

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`age` is an `int`.  `int` is a signed 32-bit integer that doesn't allow nulls. If you want to allow it to be `null`, change its type to `int?` which makes it a [Nullable Type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1t3y8s4s%28v=VS.100%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Tom, I'm not entirely sure why this is happening, at least based on the example you've pasted. Is your XML completely hand-crafted?

Or are you actually having problems round-tripping? In other words, you serialize an object of this type, and then when you try to deserialize it, you run into the problem of Age not being read completely.

I suspect it's the former (hand-written or user-crafted XML, at least partially). What I would recommend is serializing out exactly the same object via DataContractSerializer (i.e., start with the desired target object and write it out to XML) and compare what's different from the XML you're trying to read in.

Answer (score 0):

If you could just remove the namespace from your Parent class, it should be able to deserialize accurately.

```
[DataContract] // Removed Namespace or keep both namespace the same
public class Parent
{
    [DataMember]
    public Child Child;
    [DataMember]
    public string FirstName;
    [DataMember]
    public string LastName;
}

[DataContract]
public class Child
{
    [DataMember]
    public int Age;
}
```